# Default Typescript React-Native project gives 200 errors

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have created a react native project with the following command.
VS Code gives about 200 ts errors in the Problems section but I am able to compile with tsc.

```
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

Any idea why VS Code is doing like this? Thanks

Comment: do you have eslint installed and enabled? try `npm remove -g eslint` and also check your extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have eslint installed and enabled?

try `npm remove -g eslint` and also check your extensions

I am suspecting that you have an incompatible linting extension.

---

another reason might be vscode identifies *.ts as typescript files and *.tsx as typescript react files. when you open file check bottom right corner of the vscode to see how the file is interpreted.

Comment: eslint is not installed globally or locally. I disabled the extensions TSLint, ESLint and Flow. I check right-bottom and it was 'Typescript' then I updated it to 'Typescript react'. But App.tsx errors have not gone. When I create another tsx file I see that there is no error.

Comment: Weird, after I refresh VS code, errors in app.tsx have gone. So now, I will try to investigate what the source of these errors. Thank you